# How to add an image at a corner in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, flutter

Need your help to do a card like shown below.

[image: Image for your ref]

I am blind for that right top corner image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Row` with `Expanded` widgets to fit the layout in your container. The `flex` parameter is the percentual value to expand, so in your case you want to have x% of space to create your image widget and the rest if for the text.

By using the flex parameter, you're making sure your layout will adapt in case the container grow.

> Remember `Row` are containers that constraint your code horizontally. You also have `Column` for vertical and `Stack` to stack widgets.

```dart
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            flex: 75
            child: YourTextWidget(),
        ),
        Expanded(
            flex: 25,
            child: YourImageWidget(),
        ),
    ],
)
```

Hope I've helped!

Comment: `[Stack]`+`[Positioned]`  is also a solution.